# Cache performance of vectors, matrices and quaternions

Tags: c++, c, arrays, optimization, data-structures

I've noticed on a number of occasions in the past, C and C++ code that uses the following format for these structures:

```
class Vector3
{
    float components[3];
    //etc.
}

class Matrix4x4
{
    float components[16];
    //etc.
}

class Quaternion
{
    float components[4];
    //etc.
}
```

My question is, will this lead to any better cache performance than say, this:

```
class Quaternion
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    //etc.
}
```

...Since I'd assume the class members and functions are in contiguous memory space, anyway? I currently use the latter form because I find it more convenient (however I can also see the practical sense in the array form, since it allows one to treat axes as arbitrary dependant on the operation being performed).

---

Afer taking some advice from the respondents, I tested the difference and it is actually slower with the array -- I get about 3% difference in framerate. I implemented operator[] to wrap the array access inside the Vector3. Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but I doubt it since that should be inlined anyway. The only factor I could see was that I could no longer use a constructor initializer list on `Vector3(x, y, z)`. However when I took the original version and changed it to no longer use constructor initialiser lists, it ran very marginally slower than before (less than 0.05%). No clue, but at least now I know the original approach was faster.

Comment: Why not simply define accessors ? (`vec.x()`, `vec.y()`, ...)

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's exactly what I've just finished doing. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These declarations are not equivalent with respect to memory layout.

```
class Quaternion
{
    float components[4];
    //etc.
}
```

The above guarantees that the elements are continuous in memory, while, if they are individual members like in your last example, the compiler is allowed to insert padding between them (for instance to align the members with certain address-patterns).

Whether or not this results in better or worse performance depends on your mostly on your compiler, so you'd have to profile it.

Comment: Is the compiler free to add paddings also in C, or only in C++?

Comment: Could you give a concrete practical example where there would be padding inserted in the latter case but not in the former? Or is this purely a theoretical argument?

Comment: @aix: I guess with `float` it would probably never be the case. In general, on some platforms memory access is much faster if the addresses are aligned in a certain way (e.g. starting at a multiple of 4).

Comment: @amit: I don't know, but I think so, because the declaration above is also a POD, and PODs are guaranteed to have the same memory layout they would have in C.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: I am asking because I am almost sure I remember an old linux version, in which one of the structs in sched.c used "magic", which assumes no padding in the struct... I am trying to find out/remember which version and what struct that was. Was it a potential bug? Or is it guaranteed for C? :\

Comment: @BjörnPollex You may or may not be right, but even a warning that there may be padding is enough for me to change to an array format, and I foresee needing arbitrary axis swapping anyway. Accepted, thanks.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, and don't forget that negative integers need not use twos complement ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau If that was an optimisation tip, it just went "Whoosh!" right over my head. ;) Are you suggesting fixed point?

Comment: @Nick No, it was a little sarcastic example of something (non-twos-complement negatives) that can be true (and result in UB if not cared for) but is practically never true, like padding between 32-bit IEEE floats in a structure. Oh, I forgot, these needn't even be 32-bit IEEE floats, you know.

Comment: Ah got ya. I appreciate everyone's concern, but really, it is not a major overhaul to make this change now -- I'm still in prototyping my renderer, it's early days, and it's because the most likely candidate out of my 3 prototypes requires axis flipping, that I asked this question.

Comment: @BjörnPollex See my edit to the original question, test results FYI. I am wondering -- how could I go about finding out for certain whether GCC 4.6.2 would pack data members tightly with no buffering space between?

Comment: While the spec allows the compiler to add padding as it sees fit, no compiler adds padding between objects of the same type differently than between array elements, because it is non-sensical to do so.  So multiple fields of the same type will pretty much always be laid out exactly like an array of that type.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the performance difference from an optimization like this is minimal. I would say something like this falls into premature optimization for most code. However, if you plan to do vector processing over your structs, say by using CUDA, struct composition makes an important difference. Look at page 23 on this if interested: http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mpellegr/eleg662-09s/li.pdf

Comment: I upvoted this answer based on the useful CUDA info (thanks), yet I must say that "minimal performance difference" is all-or-nothing here. Even one extraneous byte between elements is going to have a relatively large impact on cache performance.

Comment: @NickWiggill I would say the easiest way is to test that, write out two simple test cases and try it out. Not to say your wrong, you may certainly be right, but again it sounds like premature optimization to me. Guessing how cache performance can be affected by code is different across architectures, and even with one architecture its hard to know without empirical testing.

Comment: @NickWiggill Congrats on the speedup. 3% isn't huge, but every little bit counts when performance is crucial. I would recommend taking this with a grain of salt though. Micro-optimizations like this are often not worth doing - i.e. you may not get the same performance across platforms or the compiler may actually do this optimization with different flags on. The cache is a difficult thing to master. I've heard many stories about people claiming to have better performance doing one micro-opt to actually degrade performance on another platform, which is why micro-opts are often done dynamically.

Comment: In fact, what I meant was the original method is 3% faster, not the new one (the arrays). Re your comment on micro-optimisations, yes, I find  it's a very fickle thing and not worth bothering with, particularly at these early stages, where things are going to change substantially and most if not all of those micros will be lost anyway. What is crucial is that the broader algorithms are solidly performant. But I do think a good understanding of cache performance is pretty key as the impacts can be large from what I've read.

Comment: @NickWigill It can be large. But like I said, cache performance at such a small level is a difficult to accurately predict, and pretty much impossible to predict cross-platform. That is why a lot of the cutting edge compiler optimization research being done now is about dynamically doing micro-opts with trial and error on a per-machine basis.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the compiler manages to optimize code better when using an array in this context (think at unions for example), but when using APIs like OpenGL, it can be an optimisation when calling functions like

```
void glVertex3fv(const GLfloat* v);
```

instead of calling

```
void glVertex3f(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z);
```

because, in the later case, each parameter is passed by value, whereas in the first example, only a pointer to the whole array is passed and the function can decide what to copy and when, this way reducing unnecessary copy operations.

Comment: You won't call these functions anyway, if you really care for performance (the copying of 3 floats is your least problem). And even then, maybe undefined but practically no problem, you can still use `glVertex3fv(&v.x)`.